# Does Matlab have "project files"?

Tags: matlab

For example: Rstudio uses so called *projects* - text files ending with *.Rproj*. When you click on a project file, it opens up Rstudio and sets working dir to where the project file is. Optionally, it executes any code written it. However, it does not open itself (i.e., it does not show up in the script editor).

**Is there something like that in Matlab?** If not, how to emulate it?

Currently I use to make an .m file with cd, addpath calls etc. But when I click in the file browser:

- it just opens Matlab and shows up in the script editor *without* running
- opening Matlab is what I want, but showing up in the script editor is actually redundant; I only need to run it (and use the results in my Matlab desktop session)

(What I want to avoid is having to open the script file, run it manually and then having to close it again. It is annoying!)*- edited*

Comment: Have you tried clicking the Run button or hitting F5 once it opens?

Comment: What I want to avoid is opening it and then having to close it again (because I don't need to work with it). It is just a couple of annoying things to do: Run it and then close it. Every time.

Comment: Running matlab with `-nodesktop`, you can just execute the script without actually launching everything. Saves me a lot of time.

Comment: I figured. But I actually need the desktop, I just want to have it open with some project-specific code already executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab does not have "project files" (as far as I know).
However, I think you can easily emulate what you want.

Let's suppose you have your code in a folder *C:\MyProject*:

1) Create a new m-file *C:\MyProject\MyProject.m* with all your initialization code (cd, addpath calls, global variables, whatever you need). 
Here's a simple example for demonstration purposes:

```
disp('Replace this with your initialization code');
```

2) Create a batch-file *C:\MyProject\MyProject.bat* as follows:

```
MATLAB -r "run MyProject"
```

Now, by double-clicking the batch-file you will:

- open the complete Matlab environment
- execute the script *MyProject.m* (without loading it in the script editor)

Comment: Cool! Do .bat files work on linux as well? Or is there a different way?

Comment: No, .bat-files will work only on Windows systems. On Linux you could write a shell script and make it executable. However, there is a much easier to achieve the same results in a platform-independent way... Please read my other answer regarding `startup.m`.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, MATLAB offers `startup.m` files ([online documentation](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html)).

You have to put all your initialization code in a file called `startup.m`, which needs to be located within the MATLAB search path (i.e. within your project folder). The script will be executed every time you open MATLAB by double-clicking a arbitrary m-file from your project folder.

Comment: I can see how this is the supposed workflow. It is a little different from what I want (i.e., I cannot name the script whatever I want and I *have* to open an .m file and not the "projectfile").